# filebeat doesn't forward to logstash

Tags: configuration, logstash, filebeat

I have configured filebeat as it is descripted at elastic.co

The Problem is that when I add a new log-file the data is not uploaded to logstash. What can be the problem?
I already tried different config ways but it didn't work at all.

```
################### Filebeat Configuration Example #########################

############################# Filebeat ######################################
filebeat:
  # List of prospectors to fetch data.
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - /Users/apps/*.log

      input_type: log


###############################################################################
############################# Libbeat Config ##################################
# Base config file used by all other beats for using libbeat features

############################# Output ##########################################

output:
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
    worker: 1

    index: "filebeat"

    template:
     path: "filebeat.template.json"

  ### Logstash as output
  logstash:
    # The Logstash hosts
    hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

    index: filebeat



############################# Shipper #########################################

############################# Logging #########################################

# There are three options for the log ouput: syslog, file, stderr.
# Under Windos systems, the log files are per default sent to the file output,
# under all other system per default to syslog.
logging:

  files:

    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
```

Config in logstash.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => true
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    document_id => "%{fingerprint}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are both sending Elasticsearch and logstash. You need to remove elasticsearch part if you want to send it to logstash. Taken from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/config-filebeat-logstash.html:

> If you want to use Logstash to perform additional processing on the
>   data collected by Filebeat, you need to configure Filebeat to use
>   Logstash.
>
> To do this, you edit the Filebeat configuration file to disable the
>   Elasticsearch output by commenting it out and enable the Logstash
>   output by uncommenting the logstash section

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the worker count in filebeat.yml as below?

```
  ### Logstash as output
  logstash:
    # The Logstash hosts
    hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
    # Number of workers per Logstash host.
    worker: 1
```

You should add worker count in the logstash part